# Как поместить cookie файлы в json

Tags: json, python-3.x

Есть тут скрипт который не работает ругается на кодировку

Скрипт:

```
data = dict()
            for file_name in glob.glob('*.*'):
                with open(file_name, encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    data[file_name] = f.read()
            with open('data.json', 'wb') as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "Program.py", line 230, in terminal
    data[file_name] = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\kolya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: А если вместо utf-8 подставить ascii?

Comment: Тоже ошибка  'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 2744: ordinal not in range(128)'